# VueJS - View models, children and updating values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am attempting to learn VueJS and have come across what seems to be a very basic problem. I have lots of experience with Knockout and Mustache and I think that might be what is causing me problems.

I am attempting to build a simple checkbox list to play around with the binding but my model isn't updating and I am getting the following warning in the console:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
>   whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
>   computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
>   'checked'

Here is what I am attempting to do;

A simple view model to represent a To Do item:

```
function vmToDoItem(id, title){
  this.id = id;
  this.title = title;
  this.complete = false;
}
```

A simple view model to represent all the To Do items:

```
function vmToDo(items){
  var self = this;

  self.currentFilter = 'all';
  self.items = items || [];

  self.filters = {
    all: function(){
      return self.items;
    },
    active: function(){
      return self.items.filter((item) => !item.complete);
    },
    complete: function(){
      return self.items.filter((item) => item.complete);
    }
  }
}
```

A component to represent the To Do items:

```
Vue.component('checkbox-item',
             {
                props: ['text', 'checked'],
                template: '#checkbox-item-template',
                computed: {
                  prefix: function(){
                    return !this.checked ? 'fa-circle' : 'fa-check-circle';
                  }
                },
                methods: {
                  clicked: function(){
                    this.checked = !this.checked;
                  }
                }
              })
```

The corresponding template:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="checkbox-item-template">
  <span @click="clicked">
    <span :class="'far ' + prefix"></span>
    {{ text }}
  </span>
</script>
```

The markup for the 'app':

```
<div id="app">
  <checkbox-item 
             v-for="item in items" 
             class="todoItem" 
             :key="item.id"
             v-bind:text="item.title"
             v-bind:checked="item.complete">
  </checkbox-item>
  <br />
  <span>Items unchecked: {{ remaining }}</span>
</div>
```

Initialization code:

```
var mdl = new vmToDo();
mdl.items.push(new vmToDoItem(1, 'test 1'));
mdl.items.push(new vmToDoItem(2, 'test 2'));

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: mdl,
  computed: {
    remaining: function(){
      let currentFilter = this.$data.filters[this.$data.currentFilter];
      return currentFilter().length;
    }
  }
});
```

Everything renders just fine and clicking one of the items toggles the checkbox correctly however the underlying item in mdl.items is not updated and I get the aforementioned warning in the console.

I suspect that the two-way binding works differently than I expected, I expected it to function like Knockout, and I am at a loss as to how to make this function the way that I would anticipate.

For the sake of brevity here is a full snippet for my issue:

```js
function vmToDoItem(id, title){
  this.id = id;
  this.title = title;
  this.complete = false;
} 

function vmToDo(items){
  var self = this;
  
  self.currentFilter = 'all';
  self.items = items || [];
  
  self.filters = {
    all: function(){
      return self.items;
    },
    active: function(){
      return self.items.filter((item) => !item.complete);
    },
    complete: function(){
      return self.items.filter((item) => item.complete);
    }
  }
}

Vue.component('checkbox-item',
             {
                props: ['text', 'checked'],
                template: '#checkbox-item-template',
                computed: {
                  prefix: function(){
                    return !this.checked ? 'fa-circle' : 'fa-check-circle';
                  }
                },
                methods: {
                  clicked: function(){
                    this.checked = !this.checked;
                  }
                }
              })

var mdl = new vmToDo();
mdl.items.push(new vmToDoItem(1, 'test 1'));
mdl.items.push(new vmToDoItem(2, 'test 2'));

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: mdl,
  computed: {
    remaining: function(){
      let currentFilter = this.$data.filters[this.$data.currentFilter];
      return currentFilter().length;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app span.todoItem{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

#app span.todoItem span.far {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/regular.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/fontawesome.css" />

<div id="app">
  <checkbox-item 
             v-for="item in items" 
             class="todoItem" 
             :key="item.id"
             v-bind:text="item.title"
             v-bind:checked="item.complete">
  </checkbox-item>
  <br />
  <span>Items unchecked: {{ remaining }}</span>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="checkbox-item-template">
  <span @click="clicked">
    <span :class="'far ' + prefix"></span>
    {{ text }}
  </span>
</script>
```

Comment: `checked` is a prop. You are setting its value in your `clicked` function. That is the problem. See the docs on [one-way data flow](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

Comment: Hey @RoyJ, Thanks for the reply. I was reading over that part of the documentation and I understand now that it is a one-way binding however how would someone go about achieving this? basically, I want the control 'checkbox-item' to update the value of the corresponding model when it is clicked. Then I would be able to reuse this component for any checkbox type item I want. Would I need to access `this.$root.data.items`, find the item in there and then update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Props down, events up" is the rule to remember. Data is passed from parent to child via props. Events are emitted by children and handled by parents (events up is not a strict rule, but is the only way changes should go up the tree). In this case, instead of trying to assign a value to your prop `checked`, emit an event and put a handler on the component so that the parent will catch the event and act accordingly:

```
  <checkbox-item v-for="item in items" class="todoItem" :key="item.id" :text="item.title" :checked="item.complete" @click="item.complete = !item.complete">
  </checkbox-item>
```

I modified your snippet to work this way and also to list the values of item.complete so you can see the data update happening.

```js
function vmToDoItem(id, title) {
  this.id = id;
  this.title = title;
  this.complete = false;
}

function vmToDo(items) {
  var self = this;

  self.currentFilter = 'all';
  self.items = items || [];

  self.filters = {
    all: function() {
      return self.items;
    },
    active: function() {
      return self.items.filter((item) => !item.complete);
    },
    complete: function() {
      return self.items.filter((item) => item.complete);
    }
  }
}

Vue.component('checkbox-item', {
  props: ['text', 'checked'],
  template: '#checkbox-item-template',
  computed: {
    prefix: function() {
      return !this.checked ? 'fa-circle' : 'fa-check-circle';
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clicked: function() {
      this.$emit('click');
    }
  }
})

var mdl = new vmToDo();
mdl.items.push(new vmToDoItem(1, 'test 1'));
mdl.items.push(new vmToDoItem(2, 'test 2'));

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: mdl,
  computed: {
    remaining: function() {
      let currentFilter = this.$data.filters[this.$data.currentFilter];
      return currentFilter().length;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app span.todoItem {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

#app span.todoItem span.far {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/regular.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/fontawesome.css" />

<div id="app">
  <checkbox-item v-for="item in items" class="todoItem" :key="item.id" :text="item.title" :checked="item.complete" @click="item.complete = !item.complete">
  </checkbox-item>
  <br />
  <span>Items unchecked: {{ remaining }}</span>
  <div v-for="item in items">
    {{item.complete}}
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="checkbox-item-template">
  <span @click="clicked">
    <span :class="'far ' + prefix"></span> {{ text }}
  </span>
</script>
```

Comment: `{{ remaining }}` isn't reactive

Comment: I know, but that wasn't part of the question and I didn't want to figure it out.

Comment: Perhaps, it would be better to rewrite the code in more Vue-ish way?

Comment: Hey @RoyJ thanks for the answer! After looking at it I don't see what's handling the click event and updating the object in `vm`, so I guess my follow up question is; how is the object inside `vm.items` being updated with this solution?

Comment: Hey @Styx what would be a more Vue-ish way to do this? I'm new to Vue so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The child handles a native click event by calling `clicked`, which `emit`s a click event to the parent. The parent has `@click="item.complete = !item.complete"` to toggle the value of `complete`.

Comment: Oh! I see that now, very clever. Thanks for your help.